# Are ([career], [career-path]), and ([job], [jobs]) tags synonyms?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

When tagging this question: [How can I apply to be an adjunct faculty?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/4930/344), I came across four tags that could either be synonyms or at least have more distinct definitions.

To be clear, I think that these could either be merged into two or even one tag with synonyms.

For reference, here are the current definitions of these tags:

- [career](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/career): Career is a person's "course or progress through life (or a distinct portion of life)". Questions related to academic career comes under this tag.
- [career-path](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/career-path): Queries related to progression of academics in various capacities from a student to a professor and the various stages involved in the process.

The following should be considered as well:

- [job](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/job): Refers to academic job, its advantages and disadvantages. Also related to duties and responsibilities associated with an academic job and academic job search.
- [jobs](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jobs): (no summary)

Answer (score 5):

[job](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/job) and [jobs](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jobs) are definitely synonyms, and they have been merged.

I'm not as sure about [career](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/career) and [career-path](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/career-path), but I'd love to hear what everyone else about those.

Answer (score 3):

Intuitively, I'd say that [career](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/career) and [career-path](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/career-path) are equivalent. More precisely, I don't see many questions that would qualify for one tag but not the other.

Answer (score 0):

job now seems to be frequently misapplied, as per its own description and that of job-search. Sometimes people use both (which is reasonable but perhaps not optimal for job); other times they don't use job-search. Can someone help me figure out if there's a process to do something about that?